# MSSQL Data Parsing

Tags: sql-server, linker

I don't know what its called so I'll just try to explain.

Lets say there are two tables, `tableA` and `tableB`.

- In `tableA` there is a column that has a number (eg. 105)
- In `tableB` there is a column that has a text (eg. 'This')

105 means 'This'.

So a number is stored in the `A` table w/c has a meaning in the `B` table.

I want to get the `tableA` number, but when its displayed it will display 'This'.

Logic: If result from A is 105, then display equivalent text from B where id is 105.
Displays: THIS

```
SELECT TOP 1
    CHAR_KEY AS charid,
    USER_KEY AS userid,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring(char_data, 9, 16)) AS name,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 7, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS level,
    CONVERT(INT,substring(char_data, 25, 1)) AS type,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 263, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS strength,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 265, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS wisdom,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 267, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS dexterity,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 269, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS charisma,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 271, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS intelligence,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 273, 2)) as BINARY(2))) AS constitution,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 309, 4)) as BINARY(4))) AS fame,
    CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 33, 4)) as BINARY(4))) AS guild,
    CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1)) AS permission
FROM CHAR_DATA0 WHERE CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1))=0x00 ORDER BY level DESC
```

The query to get the name of the guild.

```
SELECT 
    guild_name
FROM guild_data WHERE guild_key=guild
```

What I'm trying to get is the `guild`.

Example from the first SELECT query the `guild` results: 518

on the table guild_data, a column guild_name contains the name of the guild 518.
518 is the guild_key.

Please help, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    guild_data.guild_name
FROM CHAR_DATA0
inner join guild_data on guild_key = CONVERT(INT,cast(reverse(substring(char_data, 33, 4)) as BINARY(4)))
WHERE CONVERT(INT, substring(char_data, 261, 1))=0x00 ORDER BY level DESC
```

Comment: @user1543644 Modified to use your actual queries as I understand them.

Comment: Hello, it still displays the same output as my last query. the guild is still in numbers. I'm trying to figure it out now if there is something missing. Thanks alot.

Comment: @user1543644 Add guild_data.guild_name to your select as I have modified above.

Comment: the table CHAR_DATA0 contains the 518 number. The table guild_data contains the guild_name and guild_key, where guild_key=518 is guild_name=fidelis

Comment: Thanks, Alright. I'll check it. I have to go now. Be back later.

Comment: @user1543644 Yes, I understand.  You need to join the two tables as above.  I removed the extraneous columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need a "select" and a "join"

```
  select b.text
  from tablea a 
  inner join tableb b on a.id = b.id
  where a.id = 105
```

To make this work, however, you need "id" in BOTH tables.

Comment: I have edited my first post. My query is a bit different, because the number data is from a substring.